# Javascipt to hide by class and the name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide by the class and the name attribute in div

This wont work

```
$("div.ind_post").find("[name^='1']").hide();
```

This work

```
$("div.ind_post").hide();
$("div").find("[name^='1']").hide();
```

I wonder why i can hide by the element with class, or the name, but i cannot hide with class and name both.
so my question is how to hide within the class, by a specify name, thanks!

Comment: You need to show us your HTML too...

Answer (score 2):

[`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) searches descendants

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

You should do

```
$("div.ind_post[name^='1']").hide();
```

---

I suspect the reason why `$("div").find("[name^='1']").hide();` worked is that you had some `div` element higher up in the DOM hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that `name` attributes are **not allowed** on `div` elements.

`find` searches the **descendants** of the selected elements.

If you want an element which matches a class selector and an attribute selector then you need to either search for them together in the first place:

```
 $("div.ind_post[name^='1']")
```

or `filter` the collection of matched elements on the extra rule

```
 $("div.ind_post").filter("[name^='1']").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation!